# In which XML file should I use depends element (Magento)?

Tags: php, xml, magento

We know there are 2 necessary XML files for module development in Magento.

1. Package_Module.xml
2. etc/config.xml

Some people use `<depends>` (if depends on any existing module) tag inside first XML file & some in second file

2.)

```
<modules>
    <Company>
        <NewProduct>
            <version>0.7.32</version>
            <depends>
                <!-- no dependencies -->
            </depends>
        <NewProduct>
    </Company>
<modules>
```

1.)

```
<modules>
    <(NameSpace_ModuleName)>
        <active>[true|false]</active>
        <codePool>[core|community|local]</codePool>
        <depends>
            <(AnotherNameSpace_ModuleName) />
        </depends>
        <version>(version_number)</version>
    </(NameSpace_ModuleName)>
</modules>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Configuration is compiled in multiple steps. Because of this, the `<depends>` node should be defined in the module declaration file in `app/etc/modules/`.

**Note that `<depends>` directives only establish a load order (or error) for module `config.xml` files AND NOTHING ELSE.**

Comment: i'm pretty sure that it also throws errors when dependend module is disabled.

Comment: yes when i also try to disable shipping module(in my depend case) from configuration=>advanced its give error

Comment: Classic (and understandable) mistake - the interface in the backend does not disable the module it disables module output and may or may not disable the module's layout XML from being loaded.